# Как в ilovepdf исправить ошибку "This task can't be processed. Check why in the params. (Elements cannot be blank.)"

Tags: php, pdf

пытаюсь добавить текст в пдф в ilovepdf вот так

```
require_once("vendor/autoload.php");
use Ilovepdf\EditpdfTask;
use Ilovepdf\Editpdf\TextElement;
try {
$PDF = new EditpdfTask('project_public_....','secret_key_....');
$editpdfTask = $PDF->newTask('editpdf');
$file = $editpdfTask->addFile('....');
$textElem = new TextElement();
$textElem->setText("This is a sample text");
$editpdfTask->addElement($textElem);
$editpdfTask->setOutputFilename('pdfv1');
$editpdfTask->execute();
$editpdfTask->download('pdf_folder/');
    }
catch (\Exception $e) {
    echo '<pre>';
   print_r($e);
   echo '</pre>';
    }
```

но получаю ошибку "This task can't be processed. Check why in the params. (Elements cannot be blank.)" кто то знает почему такая ошибка получается? в документации апи в примерах все также описано как рабочий код но непонятно почему не работает, путь к файлу правильный и другие модули как например compress работают, ошибка случается если добавлять текст

Answer (score 0):

Если кому то будет полезно причина была прикольная, через composer почему то загрузилось некорректно и все исправилось когда я перезалил себе папку src с гитхаб вручную